# when opening storyboard file in xcode 6.1, mac turns black

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I have problem  in Xcode. I got black screen when I load storyboard of any project project. It was working fine before but suddenly when i changed background of one storyboard file, it started turning the screen totally black. MAC OS Mavericks, xcode 6.1. Please tell me cause and way for solving this problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your Xcode downloaded from mac apple store, if your mac is too old ,you can search Xcode4.6 or earlier edition.

Comment: everything is fine. i updated to 6.1 a week ago with no problem and after a week i get this error